# Recommended way to wait for a response to a Twilio SMS message

Tags: c#, twilio, asp.net-mvc-5.2, twilio-api

I have a series of questions that I need to send to a user's phone via SMS and I would like to wait for a certain amount of time to allow the user to respond before I incorporate other logic such as maybe re-sending the message or asking the user to try again later.

Is there a recommended way to implement this behavior utilizing the Twilio SMS api?

Also, I am currently using an older version of Twilio, though I am intending to update to current after I complete adding the new features to an old implementation. The package versions I am currently using are shown below:

```
<package id="Twilio" version="3.6.11" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Twilio.Mvc" version="3.1.12" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Twilio.TwiML" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: You need the user to respond by sending response back to the sms you sent? Or you are sending some code to the user and waiting for the user to enter that code in UI?

Comment: I need the user to respond to the questions by entering numeric digits corresponding to his/her answer. So for example: enter 1 for yes, enter 2 for no, or enter 3 if you are unsure.

Comment: Twilio have feature of notifying you when user sends message to any of the twilio registered number. You can record that response from user. You need run a background service which will check if response is recorded in stipulated time else send another sms.

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  I've used Hangfire to schedule background jobs with a lot of success.  https://www.hangfire.io/